# Computed properties depending on each other with different behaviors on Vue 1 and 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, computed-properties

I'm having an issue where I have input boxes with formatted numbers which contain a computed property each. When I'm changing an input Vue will automatically recompute the number and I won't be able to type exactly what I need. This only happens with Vue 2.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',

  data: function() {
    return {
      direction: 'hi',
      target: 49.99,
      maxRoll: Big(99.99),
      oddsDividend: Big(100),
    }
  },
  watch: {
    direction: function() {
      this.target = this.maxRoll.minus(this.target).abs()
    }
  },
  computed: {
    chance: {
      get: function() {
        return this.direction === 'hi' ?
          this.maxRoll.minus(this.target).toFixed(2) :
          Big(this.target).toFixed(2)
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        this.target = this.direction === 'hi' ?
          this.maxRoll.minus(newValue).toFixed(2) :
          Big(newValue).toFixed(2)
      }
    },
    odds: {
      get: function() {
        return this.direction === 'hi' ?
          this.oddsDividend.div(this.maxRoll.minus(this.target)).toFixed(4) :
          this.oddsDividend.div(this.target).toFixed(4)
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        this.target = this.direction === 'hi' ?
          this.oddsDividend.div(newValue).minus(this.maxRoll).abs().toFixed(2) :
          this.oddsDividend.div(newValue).toFixed(2)
      }
    },
  }
});
```

As an example, here's a Fiddle with Vue 2: https://jsfiddle.net/fc4b60n3/
Try to type the number 234, or any other number, on the second input box. It will only capture the first digit and perform all calculations with that.

Now with Vue 1: https://jsfiddle.net/fc4b60n3/1/
Here you can type the full number e.g. 234 and only when you lose focus of the input it will recalculate its own computed property. This is the behavior I want, but I must use Vue 1 for it and it is not compatible with my current setup.

So my questions are. What changed between those Vue versions to cause this? How can I have the code work like I want using Vue 2?

**EDIT** Forum thread, to keep everything in sync: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/96370

Answer (score 1):

i think v-model 
on v1 use `onchange` event ( wait till lose focus then change )
on v2 it use `oninput` event ( as soon as you type a new line )

so to fix your code use `v-bind:value` and `onChange event` to set that value instead of `v-model`

Comment: But if you look at the v1 Fiddle it is still doing the calculations as I type it.

Comment: I've replaced `v-model="odds"` with `v-bind:value="odds" v-on:change="odds= $event.target.value"` and it waits till lose focus, but doesn't update the other fields as I type, like Vue 1 does.

Comment: you can work around this by using v-model="odds" , remove toFixed(4) ( the part that add those .000 ) from computed odds , make a new method formatodds that add those toFixed(4) ,   add on:change='formatodds' , so now you can calculate normaly but only when you lose focus the value get changed

Comment: Unfortunately that still won't work because even without the decimal cases, it will still recalculate, for example if you input 234 it will recalculate to 232. The real issue here is having the input being locked exclusively for the user while on focus. I have no clue how or why Vue 1 does that but Vue 2 doesn't. I've settled to using the lazy modifier `v-model.lazy="odds"` for now but that is not what I want for production.

Comment: So if I wanted to type in 2345 I couldn't because it would recalculate and replace my input with 232 before I could type the 5.